# Is there a way to send 2 messages with one request? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm kinda new to using requests in general, and I've been wondering if there's a way to send 2 messages with one requests? Here's my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def request(ctx):
    requests.post(f'https://discord.com/api/v10/channels/{ctx.channel.id}/messages', headers=headers, data={'content': ['first message', 'second message']})
```

I didn't really try anything else. As I said, I'm kinda new to requests. The command itself works fine, but it only sends "first message".

Comment: why are u using requests when u could just use discord.py itself for this.

Comment: cause i wanna learn more about requests

Comment: alright, but to answer your question you cant send two messages at the same time with one single request thats not possible

Answer (score 0):

Like [boez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17381704/boez) said, it's not possible to do this. 
If you look at how Discord sends messages to their own API, they use `\n` for the "2nd message."

**But since you said you want to look more into requests, here is the full raw Discord message data.**

Content

```
test 1
test 2
```

```json
{
    "activity": null,
    "activityInstance": null,
    "application": null,
    "applicationId": null,
    "attachments": [],
    "author": {
        "id": "1234567890123456",
        "username": "johndoe",
        "discriminator": "0",
        "avatar": "2d9fa43d56ee4585c0e1333fd34e5ea5",
        "avatarDecorationData": null,
        "verified": true,
        "bot": false,
        "system": false,
        "mobile": true,
        "desktop": true,
        "premiumType": 3,
        "flags": 0,
        "publicFlags": 0,
        "purchasedFlags": 10,
        "premiumUsageFlags": 4,
        "nsfwAllowed": true,
        "guildMemberAvatars": {},
        "hasBouncedEmail": false,
        "globalName": "John Doe"
    },
    "blocked": false,
    "bot": false,
    "call": null,
    "channel_id": "1234567890123456",
    "codedLinks": [],
    "components": [],
    "content": "test 1\ntest 2", <-- here 
    "editedTimestamp": null,
    "embeds": [],
    "flags": 0,
    "giftCodes": [],
    "id": "1209685049281085583",
    "interaction": null,
    "interactionData": null,
    "interactionError": null,
    "isSearchHit": false,
    "loggingName": null,
    "mentionChannels": [],
    "mentioned": false,
    "mentionEveryone": false,
    "mentionRoles": [],
    "mentions": [],
    "messageReference": null,
    "nonce": "1234567890123456789",
    "pinned": false,
    "reactions": [],
    "referralTrialOfferId": null,
    "state": "SENT",
    "stickerItems": [],
    "stickers": [],
    "timestamp": "2024-02-21T02:16:30.610Z",
    "tts": false,
    "type": 0,
    "webhookId": null
}
```